# Lightswitch 1 to 0..1 relationship, how to add the supporting row in edit screen?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Have a Lightswitch 2012 project with two tables that have a 1 to 0..1 relationship between them. When I open the edit screen for the row on the "1" side and the row does not yet exist on the "0..1" side, I get disabled text boxes for that data. But there's no button to add a new row on the "0..1" side. Is there a way to do this, or have to resort to code?

**First Attempt**

Tried the following code:

```
partial void Bill_Loaded(bool succeeded)
{
    if (this.Bill.Summary == null)
    {
        Summary summary = this.DataWorkspace.Data.Summaries.AddNew();
        brief.ID = this.Bill.ID;
        this.DataWorkspace.Data.SaveChanges();
        this.Refresh();
    }               
    this.SetDisplayNameFromEntity(this.Bill);
}
```

It works, but seems a hack that I am loading the screen, adding the `Summary` and then refreshing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
partial void Bill_Loaded(bool succeeded)
{
    if (this.Bill.Summary == null)
        this.Bill.Summary = new Summary();
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, that does not refresh the screen to allow data entry in the summary text box.